# Data persistence - How to persist list of data

Tags: flutter

I have a list of data that I need to persist and I have no idea where to start, a little background of what i'm making. A app that controls the gpio pins of raspberry pi via http request although currently I am just working on the ui and haven't actually started making the webserver to process the http requests.

the following is the model im using for development and what i'm trying to save.

```
class Pin {
  int index;
  int pinNum;
  String name;
  bool isOn;

  Pin (int pinNum, String name, bool isOn, int index) {
    this.pinNum = pinNum;
    this.name = name;
    this.isOn = isOn;
    this.index = index;
  }
}

Pin controller1 = Pin(18, "light", true, 0);
Pin controller2 = Pin(20, "tv", false, 1);
Pin controller3 = Pin(24, "blender", true, 2);
Pin controller4 = Pin(34, "television", false, 3);


List <Pin>controllers = [
  controller1,
  controller2,
  controller3,
  controller4,
];
```

And this is the code my listview builder is in (sorry for the poor formatting i'm still learning)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "package:gpio_control/models/pin.dart";
import 'package:slide_popup_dialog/slide_popup_dialog.dart' as slideDialog;

class GpioScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GpioScreenState createState() => _GpioScreenState();

}

class _GpioScreenState extends State<GpioScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int selectedIndex = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Gpio Control",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.yellow[200]
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 1,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              color: Colors.yellow[200],
            ),
            iconSize: 40,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settings');
            }, //settings
          )
        ],

      ),

      floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 40,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          elevation: 2,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addPin');
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.black54,
            size: 30,
          ),

        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: controllers.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {

                void _showDialog() {
                  slideDialog.showSlideDialog(
                    context: context,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,80,5,10),
                          child: Text(
                            "Are you sure you want to delete this configuration?",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.yellow[200],
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "(Any deleted configurations can not be recoved)",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.yellow[200],
                              fontSize: 10,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                          child: ButtonTheme(
                            minWidth: 300,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedIndex = i;
                                  controllers.remove(controllers.removeAt(selectedIndex));
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                });
                              },

                              color: Colors.yellow[200],
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow[200])
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                  "Delete"
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    barrierColor: Colors.yellow[100].withOpacity(0.7),
                    pillColor: Colors.yellow[200],
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                  );
                }

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.yellow[200],
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 6, 0, 0),
                                  child: Text("pin"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                  child: Text(
                                    controllers[i].pinNum.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 25
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                                Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                      .spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Center(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            25, 0, 0, 25),
                                        child: Text(
                                          controllers[i].name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                      .spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          0, 0, 10, 20),
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            if (controllers[i].isOn) {
                                              controllers[i].isOn = false;
                                              print(controllers[i].isOn);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                              controllers[i].isOn = true;
                                            }
                                          });
                                        },

                                        icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.power_settings_new,
                                            color: controllers[i].isOn == true
                                                ? Colors.green[600]
                                                : Colors.red[600]
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.yellow[150],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          0, 0, 0, 20),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            selectedIndex = i;
                                            print("new index");

                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            _showDialog();

                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                          iconSize: 30,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



}
```

if you need any more context please full free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to have hundreds / thousands of controllers I recommend using [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) instead of using SQLite, it is easier and the performance penalty is almost non existent.

You could manually declare each key:value pair for each of the controllers, but that isn't a nice solution, especially if you end up needing more controllers in the future. Instead I recommend modifying your Pin class to include json to/from mapping, and one more class to store all of the pins, like so:

```
class AllPins {
  List<Pin> allPins;

  AllPins(this.allPins);

  AllPins.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['AllPins'] != null) {
      allPins = new List<Pin>();
      json['AllPins'].forEach((v) {
        allPins.add(new Pin.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.allPins != null) {
      data['AllPins'] = this.allPins.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

}


class Pin {
  int index;
  int pinNum;
  String name;
  bool isOn;

  Pin (int index, int pinNum, String name, bool isOn) {
    this.pinNum = pinNum;
    this.name = name;
    this.isOn = isOn;
    this.index = index;
  }

  Pin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    index = json['index'];
    pinNum = json['pinNum'];
    name = json['name'];
    isOn = json['isOn'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['index'] = this.index;
    data['pinNum'] = this.pinNum;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['isOn'] = this.isOn;
    return data;
  }

}
```

Then create methods for loading / saving / deleting AllPins from shared preferences like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
// load
Future<AllPins> loadAllPins() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var allPinsTemp = prefs.getString('AllPins');
  if(allPinsTemp!=null){
    return(AllPins.fromJson(json.decode(allPinsTemp)));
  }else{
    return null;
  }
}

// save
saveAllPins(AllPins allPins) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setString("AllPins",json.encode(allPins.toJson()));
}

// delete
deleteAllPins() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.remove("AllPins");
}
```

And lastly here is how you can use the the code above somewhere in your app:

```
  await deleteAllPins();

  List<Pin> pinList = new List<Pin>();
  pinList.add(new Pin(1,4,"test1",true));
  pinList.add(new Pin(2,7,"test2",false));

  AllPins allPins = new AllPins(pinList);
  await saveAllPins(allPins);

  AllPins allPinsReadFromSP = await loadAllPins();
  if(allPinsReadFromSP != null){
    print("Total pins loaded: " + allPinsReadFromSP.allPins.length.toString());
    for(int i=0; i<allPinsReadFromSP.allPins.length; i++){
      print("i:"+i.toString());
      print("index: " + allPinsReadFromSP.allPins[i].index.toString());
      print("pinNum: " + allPinsReadFromSP.allPins[i].pinNum.toString());
      print("name: " + allPinsReadFromSP.allPins[i].name);
      print("isOn: " + allPinsReadFromSP.allPins[i].isOn.toString());
    }
  }else{
    print("Null was returned for AllPins.");
  }
```

As an added bonus you can use the already made json mapping later on for posting / getting data from your web server later on.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused how would i go about changing my above code using the controllers list to using the AllPins class in my list view builder.

Comment: My class/variable naming could have been better, but in any case it is not that complicated. AllPins class is there to make saving and loading data from SharedPreferences a bit easier. AllPins class contains a List<Pin> called allPins , this is the same thing as your "controllers". So in your code when you do this `child:ListView.builder(itemCount: controllers.length,`' just replace it with `child:ListView.builder(allPinsReadFromSP.allPins.length` and obviously all other references like: `controllers[i].pinNum.toString()`  need to be replaced accordingly.

Comment: I know i'm asking a lot of questions that probably have simple answers but where is this allPinsReadFromSP coming from im trying to us it as you've described but there is no method or variable in the class that goes by that name.

Comment: Did you read my final (3rd) code block? That part has example usage of everything said in the 1st two code blocks. allPinsReadFromSP is mentioned there, it is just an instance of AllPins.

Comment: Yes I  did read that final code block but I am confused about where to put that snippet in.